# RTL (right-to-left) and Persian support in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4

I want to localize my admin package by making the views RTL and translating the whole panel to Persian so that people with similar requirements can use it.(It will be my delight)
Would you please tell me which files I should edit??

site:
http://xtex.ir/admin/login

user:demo@android.com

pass:admin

Comment: is this a laravel admin package ?

Comment: yes of course!!

Comment: add `bootstrap-rtl` style to your front-end assets!

Answer (score 2):

You have to do the following tasks
1-import CSS & JS bootstrap-rtl (LTR => RTL)
Use [bootstrap-rtl](http://bootstrap.rtlcss.com/) instead of bootstrap css & js files,
you can access css & js files in this directory :

> {YOUR-PROJECT-NAME}\resources\assets

(Do not forget to compile the css and js files, You need to use this command in the project directory => `npm run watch`)

2-Change lang Folder
Laravel for showing message and validation uses lang folder and you should add `fa` folder in lang folder.you can access `lang folder` in this directory :

> {YOUR-PROJECT-NAME}\resources\lang

3-Change Application Locale Configuration
you can access in this directory :

> {YOUR-PROJECT-NAME}\config\app.php

```
 /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Locale Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| The application locale determines the default locale that will be used
| by the translation service provider. You are free to set this value
| to any of the locales which will be supported by the application.
|
*/

'locale' => 'fa',
```

4-Use bootstrap-rtl Components
In this directory you should change bootstrap components and use bootstrap-rtl components in your `html` files:

> {YOUR-PROJECT-NAME}\resources\views